# What is the difference between NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew and NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld?

Tags: iphone, key-value-observing

```
NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
    Indicates that the change dictionary should contain the old attribute value, if applicable.
```

What does it mean old attribute value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The observer is notified when an observed key path changes it's value. The ´change` dictionary contains information related to how the observed key path has changed. This dictionary is only filled with the values according to the options that you provide when setting

- `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` - Specifies that you want to have access to the new value that the key path changed into.
- `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` - Specifies that you want to have access to the old value that the key path changed from.

If specified to be sent these old and/or new values are accessible from the `change` dictionary using these keys:

- `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey` - To access the new value.
- `NSKeyValueChangeOldKey` - To access the old/previous value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

and pick up the values via:

```
CGSize newSize = [[change objectForKey:@"new"] CGSizeValue];
CGSize oldSize = [[change objectForKey:@"old"] CGSizeValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the dictionary that is an argument of `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` contains a key-value pair that tells you the old value of the observed property.